# Getting specific values from different lists and how to

Tags: python, list, pyqt, tuples

I have two differents lists and I need to look and find the maximum and minimum  values in one of them. I am new in python and I do not know how to do this.

This is my code:

```
class A(QMainWindow):
  list_1 = [1, 75, 189, 298, 749, 15, 897, 658, 928, 93, 922, 576, 898]
  list_2 = [2, 32, 342, 2324, 435, 232, 323, 3232, 323, 98, 987, 211, 3232]

  def __init__(self):
    #A lot of stuff in here

  def get_MaxMin_values(self):
    #Here is where i need to assign the max and min value to 
    #2 different variables from list_1

    max_value = #maximum value of  list_1
    min_value = #minimum value of  list_1
```

After doing this, I need to assign to each element of `list_1` the corresponding element of `list_2`, and put this pair of elements in another list. I mean, something like create tuples with the elements of both lists in their corresponding order. For example:

```
list_tuples = [(1, 2), (75, 32), (189, 342), ......]
```

How can I accomplish this? Hope you can help me.

Comment: I am not saying that it does not works. I am saying that i do not know how to do this. The code that i wrote is just an example.

Comment: The issue is that your boilerplate code is not related to your question, and you show no effort in actually trying to implement what you want. At least for `min()` and `max()` you could have found out with a simple [google search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+list+max)

Comment: You are right @zmo. The problem was that i looked in the wrong way. I tried to find the answer looking for a `for` loop and not the simplest solution. It was my mistake.

Comment: well there are solutions with a for loop, which are algorithmics 101 level! cf the edit in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, I'll give you direct answers to your questions, and I'll leave up to you as exercise to make it fit within your `class`:

```
>>> list_1 = [1, 75, 189, 298, 749, 15, 897, 658, 928, 93, 922, 576, 898]
>>> list_2 = [2, 32, 342, 2324, 435, 232, 323, 3232, 323, 98, 987, 211, 3232]
>>> min(list_1)
1
>>> max(list_1)
928
>>> min(list_2)
2
>>> max(list_2)
3232
>>> list_1_2 = zip(list_1, list_2)
>>> list(list_1_2)
[(1, 2), (75, 32), (189, 342), (298, 2324), (749, 435), (15, 232), (897, 323), (658, 3232), (928, 323), (93, 98), (922, 987), (576, 211), (898, 3232)]
```

You have [`min()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#min) and [`max()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#max) functions available in global scope, that enables you to find the min and the max of a given `Iterable` (a list in our case).

And the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) function is your friend when you want to pair two lists, as it is coupling the values as tuples within a new list.

---

edit:

as I was saying, *you could* have tried to do something to answer your own question, let aside use google for `min`/`max`, but simply use basic algorithmics knowledge:

Find the min using a loop:

```
def find_minimum(l):
    min_value = float('inf') # use the positive infinite value per default
    for elt in l:
        if elt < min_value:
            min_value = elt
    return min_value

def find_maximum(l):
    max_value = 0
    for elt in l:
        if elt > max_value:
            max_value = elt
    return max_value
```

Obviously, the job is harder when it comes to emulate `zip()`, but it's not impossible using no python magic:

```
def zip_values(l1, l2):
    if len(l1) > len(l2):
        left, right = l1, l2
    else:
        left, right = l2, l1
    ret = []

    # below, there's a nicer way to express this using enumerate(), 
    # but I'm leaving all python magics for the purpose of the example:
    #     for position, value in enumerate(left):
    position = 0
    for value in left:
        if position < len(right):
            ret.append((left[position], right[position],))
        else:
            ret.append((left[position], None,))
        position += 1
    return ret
```

which gives:

```
>>> zip_values(list_1, list_2)
[(2, 1), (32, 75), (342, 189), (2324, 298), (435, 749), (232, 15), (323, 897), (3232, 658), (323, 928), (98, 93), (987, 922), (211, 576), (3232, 898)]
>>> find_minimum(list_1)
1
>>> find_minimum(list_2)
2
>>> find_maximum(list_1)
928
>>> find_maximum(list_2)
3232
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not know about these ones, specially about `zip()` . Does `zip()` works only with two elements? Or can I use it for 3-4 lists?

Comment: it takes as many lists as you want, making each tuple the size of the number of lists you're giving it. Quoting from the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip): "*Make an iterator that aggregates elements from each of the iterables*"

Comment: Thank you again for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the minimum and maximum values of an interable (your `list` for example) by using the following functions:

```
min(list_1)
max(list_1)
```

You can combine your two lists by using the `zip` function:

```
combined = list(zip(list_1, list_2))
```